# Can a boolean be a magic number

Tags: java, boolean, coding-style

I am wondering how I have to handle with booleans in code.

Let's say I've got a `Human` class:

```
   public class Human {

     private final static int NEWBORN = 0;

     private int age;
     private boolean married;

     public Human() {
       age = NEWBORN;
       married = false;
     }

     ...
   }
```

Is `false` in this case a magic number AND should I create a constant like I did with age?

If not, is there any case I have to handle booleans?

Comment: You might use enum instead of boolean in case of `married`. But back to your question, yes it seems reasonable to use constant here - later on you might call a method with argument for married and to help with readability of source code you might specify either MARRIED and NONMARRIED instad of true and false.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking this usage is fine. `false` is a perfectly self-explanatory value for a `boolean` named `married`.

You'll still not see that a lot, because many, many cases that you might naively model with a boolean actually involve a lot more than just two states.

For example, what if you need to handle unmarried, divorced and widowed people differently? Suddenly a simple `boolean` will not be able to accurately represent your domain data.

When in doubt, you can just introduce an `enum` (let's say `MaritalStatus`), even if it starts out with just two values. Adding additional enum values here is easier than changing from a boolean to a different type entirely.

Another common reason to use an `enum` is because you can add an explicit `UNKNOWN` value that is surprisingly often needed (and avoids the nasty use of `null` to indicate "unknown").

Comment: Absolutely agreed, i would have named the enum excactly the same. Indeed, you might often not know what additional states come in the future and it is far easier to add a new enum value than a new boolean in the using class.